# Shortcut setting of Notepad++ doesn't see a user command

Tags: windows-10, notepad++

I had to change the email of my user on a Windows 10 pc. I created a local account, changed its type to "administrator", accessed with this new local account, removed the old account (keeping its files), set the correct email to the new account.

More or less all works (and this is almost miraculous) now but I have some problem with Notepad++.

I created the command `arara` with `Plugins >  NppExec > Execute >` insert this rows:

```
NPP_SAVEALL
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
arara $(NAME_PART)
```

and saved.

If I go to `Setting > Shortcut mapper > Plugins commands` to set a shortcut, I can't find the `arara` command.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: To the downvoter: please explain what's wrong with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These setting are stored in the folder of
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++`.
As the user name has changed, the old folder no longer applies to the new user account.

If the old folder still exists, move its contents to the new folder.

If it no longer exists, you will need to recreate this user command.